# Newline Before & After Prompt (Editing An Edited .bash_profile)

Tags: bash, shell

**THE ISSUE**

I have a `.bash_profile` with the following settings:

```sh
# Git configuration

## Branch name in prompt
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
PS1='[\W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"'
```

These settings output the following prompt:

```sh
[my-git-repo(master)]$ ls
index.html
[my-git-repo(master)]$
```

Not bad. You have the base working directory (`\W`), branch indication—nice and minimal. However, I want the prompt to look like this because it's easier for me to visually parse large outputs:

```sh
[my-git-repo(master)]$ ls

index.html

[my-git-repo(master)]$
```

---

**MY ATTEMPTED SOLUTION**

So, to achieve this, I changed my `.bash_profile` to:

```sh
# Git configuration

## Branch name in prompt with newlines
source ~/.git-prompt.sh
PROMPT_COMMAND='PROMPT_COMMAND='\''PS1="\n[\W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ "'\'
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"'
```

However, the new prompt looked like this:

```sh
[my-git-repo]$ ls
index.html

[my-git-repo]$
```

As you can see, there is no newline after `ls` (my attempts to incorporate it failed), there is a newline after `index.html`, and the branch indication `(master)` has disappeared.

So close, yet I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. Help is appreciated!

Comment: The point of `PROMPT_COMMAND` is that you don't to embed arbitrary code inside `PS1`; you reset the value of `PS1` before each display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of `PS0` (supported in `bash` 4.4 or later) to add a blank line after your input. You can also simply add a newline to the beginning of your `PS1`.

```
PS0='\n'
PS1='\n[\W$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")]\$ '
```

Prior to 4.4, you would need to install a complicated `DEBUG` trap to ensure that it only adds a newline before the *first* affected command is executed; I'm not going to try to do that correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did as you said (after upgrading to bash 5.0.2) and was able to get a newline after I typed in `ls`. I just need a newline after the output so that the display follows the format `prompt-newline-output-newline-prompt` (like in the third code box in my question). Would you happen to know how to incorporate it? I tried a newline escape sequence via PS2 as a shot in the dark but no luck. Apologies, I'm new to the shell environment but interested in learning it. Appreciate the help.

Comment: The newline at the beginning of `PS1` should produce that.

Comment: You're right it did. I just didn't notice it earlier. I got the desired output! Appreciate all your help!